# How to import items into a module?

Tags: python, init, mysql-connector

I would like to create my own module to return the Mysql cursor but my module is dependent on `import mysql.connector` and `from mysql.connector import Error`.

How to I solve this? Is it something to do with directory location of the `__init__.py` file? I'm getting `NameError: name 'mysql' is not defined`.

```
from mysql import connector
from mysql.connector import Error


class SqlCnt:
    def __init__(self, db):
        """Constructor for this class."""
        self.db = db

    @classmethod
    def get_input(self):
        db = input("Enter the database:")
        try:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost",
                database=''+db,
                port=******,
                user="root",
                password="*******",
                raise_on_warnings=True,
                use_pure=False,
                autocommit=True
                )
            print("Connection made,cursor object returned")
            cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
            return cursor
        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed to connect {}".format(error))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain what error you made and ways to solve it.
You imported `connector` from `mysql` and `Error` from `mysql.connector` So you only have `connector` and `Error`. You can't use `mysql` as you did in `except mysql.connector.Error as error` because you never imported `mysql`.
So can solve this by using `import mysql`.
This is same as like accessing directories when you are in sub-directory you can't do operations on parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `from`, it takes that object alone. That is to say, after you executed this line:

```
from mysql.connector import Error
```

You don't need to use `mysql.connector` as written in this line:

```
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
```

Instead, the correct approach would be to only use the object's name, like so:

```
except Error as error:
```